# Button Trigger Not Working in My Chat Application

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I'm developing a chat application using chatbot and Python where users can interact with buttons to get more information. However, I'm facing an issue with the button trigger. When users click the button, it does not behave as expected. I need help in diagnosing and resolving this issue.

```html
// slack.py

def handle_response(result, event, say):
    if result is not None:
        if isinstance(result, dict):
            text = result.get("message")
            table = result.get("table")
            data = result.get("data")

            if text:
                getChart(data, event["channel"])

                # Create a message with a button
                message = {
                    "text": f"Response to your question: {table}",
                    "blocks": [
                        {
                            "type": "section",
                            "text": {"type": "mrkdwn", "text": f"Response to your question: {table}"},
                        },
                    ],
                    "attachments": [
                        {
                            "text": "Click the button for more information:",
                            "callback_id": "button_click",
                            "actions": [
                                {
                                    "name": "cdm",
                                    "text": "Click Me",
                                    "type": "button",
                                },
                            ],
                        },
                    ],
                }

                # Send the message with the button
                say(message)
            else:
                say({"text": "Sorry, no results found."})
        else:
            say({"text": result})
    else:
        say({"text": "Sorry, an error occurred."})
```

When a user clicks the button, the event is not triggered.

```html
// app.py

@app.action("cdm")
def handle_button_click(ack: Ack, body: dict):
    # Acknowledge the button click
    ack()
    print("Button clicked")
    print("Request Payload:", body)
    sendMessage(user_state["message_data"])
```

Steps Taken:
I've tried the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

```
Checked the documentation for button triggers.
Verified that the button's callback is correctly configured.
Examined the logs for any error messages.
```